# How can I enable xrange in Python 3 for portability?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xrange

I wrote a script which I wanted to enable for both Python 2 and Python 3.

After importing `division` and `print_function` from `__future__`, my only concern was that my `range` returns a whole array in Python 2, wasting time and memory.

I added the following 3 lines at the beginning of the script, as a workaround:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    def xrange(i):
        return range(i)
```

Then, I only used `xrange` in my code.

Is there some more elegant way to do it rather than my workaround?

Comment: There are dedicated libraries to it for you, e.g. [`six`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six).

Comment: I don't want to download 3rd party libraries

Comment: Is your script really so time- and memory-intensive that it matters?

Comment: I usually write the code for Python 3 (`dict.items()`, `range()`, ...) and accept that it may perform sub-optimally with Python 2. So far no-one ever complained because most of the time the memory overhead is negligible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simplify it a bit:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    xrange = range
```

I would do it the other way around:

```
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    range = xrange
```

If you ever want to drop Python 2.x support, you can just remove those two lines without going through all your code.

However, I strongly suggest considering the [`six` library](https://pythonhosted.org/six/). It is the de-facto standard for enabling Python 2 and 3 compatibility.

```
from six.moves import range
```

Comment: I totally agree that the other way you suggest seems more usable. It's actually making Python2's `range` act like Python3's `range`, instead of intoducing `xrange` to Python3 and leaving Python3's `range` different from Python2's `range`

Comment: in python3 the second version gives an error, as there is an "if" statement which is not executed, but then `range` variable is considered undefined. This is frustrating. I switched to `six` but it would be actually more preferable to avoid using an additional package.

Comment: @SergeyDovgal I just verified that the second version works as expected in Python 3.6.3. Or do you mean that you get an error in your IDE?

Comment: @DanielHepper You are right, I just tried it in an interpreter and it works. However, I recall that the error obtained was related to code launched after installation script. Essentially I got "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment", but I need to explain how to reproduce it. I will recall and describe a bit after.